# Stop accounts from being renamed "Anonymous Household" with NPSP?

Tags: npsp, households

I'm working with an education organization with the nonprofit starter pack installed. We're trying to create and update account records for the different colleges our students attend, but whenever we touch a record, it gets renamed to "Anonymous Household".

I'm 99% sure this is because we're using the older One-to-One account model which is causing the NPSP to do goofy things, but I'd like to avoid migrating to the recommended Household model if we can.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Our current NPSP settings are...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on target as to why this is happening.

First, under your Configuration Options for **Household Account Record Type Organization**, you'll want to change this to either "None" or set one for "Colleges and Institutions" so it doesn't try to create new Households when those records are created or updated.

You'll also want to check the User Profile settings to see what the default Record Type settings are for Household Accounts and adjust them accordingly.

Finally, if you look under the Household Object settings that you've displayed in your post, you'll see an item called **Household Creation Excluded Record Types**. I recommend you look to see if you have a default Record Type for your accounts. If you do, you'll want to add this Record Type to that list of excluded types.

If you don't have one, go back up to **One to One Record Type Household Account**" and set a default Record Type for "Students", then create another one for "Colleges and Institutions".

**Note:** I recommend you do a data export, update all existing records with their correct record types, then do a data import again with data loader to update the records to reflect the record types you'll be using going forward should they types not currently exist.

Comment: Thanks - the best fix was to just create a "College" record type and update the records.