# How to stop Rollup Helper from triggering NPSP to rename orgs "Anonymous Household"

Tags: npsp, rolluphelper, households

A bunch of Organizations (aka Accounts) have been renamed to "Anonymous Household", which we did not want renamed. We have the Nonprofit Success Pack installed, which is known to make this change. (See [this stack exchange question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156877/stop-accounts-from-being-renamed-anonymous-household-with-npsp) for a similar but unrelated issue.) All of the Organizations changed have 0 child Contacts, but oddly enough there are Orgs with 0 child Contacts which were NOT changed.

The changes happened a batch, and the timing corresponds to the first time we ran a rollup with Rollup Helper. The working theory is that the rollup, by editing every Organization record, triggered something in NPSP to change the name on some of those with 0 child Contacts. However, there are some problems with this theory. According to [this help document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000313653&type=1), changes should take place either immediately or overnight; the offending changes took place immediately, but testing showed that manually editing Orgs with 0 Contacts doesn't trigger immediate changes.

I don't understand the guts of NPSP or Rollup Helper well enough to make sense of what's happening here. Why is this NPSP functionality being triggered by Rollup Helper and not manual edits? How can I stop these apps from interacting to change records we don't want changed?

Many thanks!

EDIT: I've reposted this question [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000HDkbuSAD) per David Cheng's advice, and gotten more traction; at the time of this edit, the problem hasn't been solved, but if a solution is discovered will be found on that post.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community Why does this bot think my question fails to present "a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer"?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]  The best resource for NPSP support is the [NPSP Trailblazer group](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F94S000000kHitSAE?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC).  Also you said you have organization accounts, and yet the account name includes "Household".  Is there a reason you are using the Household Account record type to track organization accounts?  That is not best practice.

Comment: In our salesforce, the Account object has been renamed to Organization; I had thought that was part of the NPSP, though I realize now that's not the case. The Account records changed are of multiple record types.